# Всегда ли нужно следовать MVVM в Android?

Tags: android, mvc, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Насколько я знаю, MVVM нужен для того, чтобы обрабатывать поворот экрана когда в это время происходит взаимодействие с источником данных(DB,API,...). Если я ошибаюсь, поправьте. Нужно ли тогда его реализовывать, когда поворот, собственно, отключен? Если нет, тогда нужно просто отделить логику View Presentation Model? А если логика слишком простая, то достаточно ли MVC? Хотелось бы внести ясность всё-таки в этот вопрос, потому что иногда кажется, что использование какого-либо паттерна/отделение логики не требуется.

Comment: изначально нативным для андроид был именно mvc и ничего, и поворот экрана отрабатывали и приложения сложные писали. Мода на mvvm в андроид пришла от силы год-два назад, в следующем году может появиться и другой паттерн, но это не значит, что нужно все немедленно переписывать. В частности mvc удобен тем, что позволяет писать проект только средствами самого api андроид, без подключения дополнительных библиотек. Если вашу задачу можно решить проще, не надо ее искусственно усложнять в угоду модным трендам и писать не нужный конкретно в вашей ситуации код

Comment: Да, обработку поворота можно реализовать с помощью mvc и  mvp, но по сути нужно будет реализовывать такое же взаимодействие между view и model, какое реализовано уже в mvvm. А если обработка поворота экрана не нужна, то тогда не нужно будет её реализовывать в mvp и выбор между mvp и mvvm равносилен. Если я правильно понимаю

Comment: А если логика еще и не достаточно сложная чтобы делать presenter, то выбор между mvс mvp mvvm идет в пользу mvc, чтобы не нагружать приложение лишним кодом

Comment: дефолтный инструмент сохранения состояния экрана в андроид это бандл и колбэки restoreInstanceState/saveInstanceState. никакого взаимодействия, как в mvvm там никогда не было. model - данные, view - разметка, controller - активити - всё. активити при повороте пишет состояние в бандл, потом читает из него и сетит на разметку. это простое решение, но не всегда оптимальное, выбор конкретной архитектуры исходит из задач, а не трендов.

Comment: @pavlofff, Немного не согласен что MVVM это модные тренды с кучей библиотек. Это архитектура перекочевавшая в андроид из других платформ, и прзвана решать свой стек задач. Изначально как мы знаем в андроиде небыло никаких рекомендаций по использованию тех или инных архитектурных решений и MVVM вполне можно реализовать без всех бонусов. Паттерны призваны только упростить разработку/поддержку/расширение, не хотите организовывать всё это, пишите в одном активити, кто вам мешает?! Только учтите, что этот код никто не будет хотеть не читать, не поддерживать.

Comment: @Valeriy вы, видимо, как то неправильно поняли  то, что я хотел сказать или я недостаточно верно выразил мысль, потому что выводы сделали противоположные от тех, что я хотел донести. отдельно хотел бы попросить воздержаться от возвышенных оценок по поводу желаний других людей что то читать или поддерживать. есть огромное количество кода, который написан на "дефолтном" mvc android и находится много людей, желающих его читать

Answer (score 4):

MVVM, MVC и т.п. - это шаблоны проектирования архитектуры приложения. Всё это никак не связано с "обработкой поворота экрана". Если проще - это для более правильно и удобной работы с кодом (особенно в команде). И архитектура никак не влияет на взаимодействие пользователя с программой, этим всем занимаетесь непосредственно вы сами, в коде.

Всегда ли нужно следовать MVVM ? Нет. Можете следовать любой другой архитектуре, или не следовать вообще никакой и делать всё как вам удобно.

Comment: Мне кажется вы не правы в одном моменте. Лучше следовать какой-нибудь общепризнанной архитектуре,чем изобретать свою,особенно,если этот проект в дальнейшем будут поддерживать другие разработчики.

Comment: @Tony, но это же не обязанность. Вы можете следовать какой угодно архитектуре, а можете и не следовать. Вас же никто не заставляет? У вас есть выбор! Вот об этом  я и написал, что следовать не обязательно.

Comment: Выбор есть всегда - в том числе и не правильный)

Answer (score 2):

Как правильно сказал @Olmicron MVC,MVP,MVVM - это шаблоны проектирования.
Шаблоны проектирования — это один из инструментов разработчика, который помогает ему сэкономить время и сделать более качественное решение.
Они очень повышаю читабельность кода и помогают во многих вещах - например при тестировании.

Мне хотелось бы дать более четкое практическое понимание для чего нужно использовать паттерны.

Возьмем в пример разработчика который пишет код без архитектуры. Все классы в одном пакете. Никакого разделения.  Все библиотеки которые знает и пишет код как попало.
Такой проект в дальнейшем другому разработчику поддерживать будет практически невозможно.
Да чего таить,и этот разработчик  в том числе не сможет "эффективно" его поддерживать.

И возьмем противоположный пример разработчика,который использует опреденные шаблоны проектирования, которые очень сильно упрощают всем жизнь. Все классы по пакетам. Есть определенная логика и строгость. Определенные библиотеки. Всё это в совокупности сделает код более читаемым и более поддерживаемым для всех.

Comment: Хорошо, про разделение и поддерживаемость понятно. Понятно, что использование паттернов улучшает понимание кода. Но, вопрос немного в другом. Если говорить про контекст разработки в андроиде LiveData и ViewModel нужны для того чтобы сохранять состояние модели, которая отображается во View. А если это не нужно, то достаточно реализовать допустим MVP просто для отделения логики и повышения читабельности, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Хочу дополнить, что я понимаю, что обработку поворота тоже можно реализовать с помощью mvp, но для этого нужно реализовывать всё то, что уже реализовано в mvvm

Comment: Отличие MVP от mvvm лишь в использовании либы data binding, грубо говоря

Comment: Я не использовал data binding в mvvm, это же по идее не обязательно. Как я понимаю отличие mvvm от mvp это то, что в mvvm используется livedata и viewmodelproviders, с помощью которого можно получить тот же viewmodel, что был до поворота

Comment: @IlyaMaximencko В андроид сейчас есть два паттерна MVVM : тот, что реализуется через библиотеку databinding и это плюс минус то же самое, что MVVM от майкрософт с их WPF + XAML и то, что реализуется через инструменты Android Architecture Component, это где LiveData, ViewModel и вот это вот все. по сути это разные проекты с одним названием и от этого возникает путаница

Comment: @pavloff может разные реализации или именно проекты?

Comment: @IlyaMaximencko Разные проекты и разные концепции, которые не дополняют друг друга, а конкурируют. databinding появился намного раньше и реализует именно [биндинг значений на разметку](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding) по типу xaml, когда при изменении значения переменной оно тут же изменяется и на экране. Реализует паттерн MVVM в декларативном стиле и в Android Architecture Components не входит. Более того, есть [гайд по миграции](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-library-from-observable-fields-to-livedata-in-two-steps-690a384218f2).